# How to keep uploaded file between action method calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, csv

I've an application in Asp.NET MVC 4, where users upload a file to be processed 2 times. The first time I find the headers and the number of rows, and the second one (depending on some input from the user) I mapped that file to an object (It's a .csv file and I need to parse the headers). I've something like this (*The methods are consume by AJAX*):

```
[HttpPost]
public string Upload()
{
    //I get the file from HttpRequestBase
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        //Some logic...
    }
}
```

I send the headers and the number of rows to the user and then I need him to tell me some other info before I process again my file.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Process(SaveViewModel model) 
{ 
    //I don't want to make the user upload the file again and I want to use it here. 
}
```

I tried storing the file in the Session (yes I know is not a good practice) but it doesn't worked, when I tried to retrieve the file, it comes with `ContentLenght = 0`, it keeps the name and everything but the content was empty. Does anyone have another way to do it?

**EDIT 1: Showing more code to see show what's going on with the session.**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string PreUpload()
    {
        //Check if request has files
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];
            //Process the file using CsvHelper
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
            {                                
                 //Initialize the CsvReader
                 var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
                 reader.Read();
                 //Get the Headers
                 var headers = reader.FieldHeaders;
                 //get how many lines does the file has to inform the user
                 sr.DiscardBufferedData();
                 sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin); 
                 var lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
                 var linesCount = lines.Count() - 1;
                 //Create a ViewModel to send to my view
                 var viewModel = new UploadViewModel() { Headers = headers, ClientsCount = linesCount };
                 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(viewModel);
                 //Save in sesion
                 Session["file"] = file;
                 //Return my viewModel in a json
                 return json;
```

[image: If I break point before I assign the value to the Session]

And this is what I get in my second method

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string Save(SaveViewModel model) 
 {
     //Get the file from session
     var file = Session["file"] as HttpPostedFileBase;
```

[image: If I break point after retrieving]

Comment: `Does anyone have another way to do it?` What about just fixing the bug? The session does not randomly corrupt data. You made a mistake. Post the code.

Comment: It's probably best to move the file to a temporary directory, with a random-generated name, and store that name in the session. Just make sure to subscribe to the Session_End event to delete the leftover file if the user left in-between

Comment: @usr I put more info to show you whats going on with the session state

Comment: Don't store files in session. Use temp dir

Answer (score 0):

What about generating a Guid for filename, so, when uploaded it's saved on database too. You will have the key(guid) on viewmodels to control the process. If an fatal error ocurred or the user abandom the task, an subroutine must be executed (n times on day) to delete files that key (guid) was not full processed.